# Bulk updating Magento special to & from date as well as special price using SQL (Magento 1.7)

Tags: price, sql

I'm looking for a way to bulk update product special price, special to date & special from date.
I prefer to use an SQL statement but are open for other suggestions

Looking forward for an answer

A. Mikkelsen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this (obviously you should test thoroughly before using on live database):

Use this to update `special_price` value.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `price`
INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` AS `entity` ON `price`.`entity_type_id` = `entity`.`entity_type_id`
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON `price`.`attribute_id` = `attribute`.`attribute_id`
SET `price`.`value` = 123.0000
WHERE `price`.`entity_id` = 337
AND `entity`.`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product'
AND `attribute`.`attribute_code` = 'special_price';
```

Update `special_from_date` and `special_to_date` values. Timezone should be UTC.

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `time`
INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` AS `entity` ON `time`.`entity_type_id` = `entity`.`entity_type_id`
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON `time`.`attribute_id` = `attribute`.`attribute_id`
SET
    `time`.`value` = CASE
    WHEN `attribute`.`attribute_code` = 'special_from_date' THEN '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
    WHEN `attribute`.`attribute_code` = 'special_to_date' THEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00'
END
WHERE `time`.`entity_id` = 337
AND `entity`.`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product'
AND `attribute`.`attribute_code` IN ('special_from_date', 'special_to_date');
```

Comment: Can you please explain it more? What is 337? Where is the product_id that we want to update?